# MultipartBody Content-Type attributes dropped on CXF Upgrade

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, multipart

After upgrading Apache CXF from 2.4.0 to 3.1.4, the `Content-Type` header on responses from JAX-RS methods have dropped several attributes.

Under CXF 2.4.0, the header is:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; type="application/octet-stream"; boundary="uuid:61b631f1-0aa9-4cc8-ad85-3c09129ec442"; start="<DocumentName.ext>"; start-info="application/octet-stream"
```

Under CXF 3.1.4, it is:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="uuid:804168d7-70ed-44e7-a471-9647372b9224"
```

Note: attributes `type`, `start`, `start-info` missing.

Here's the code we're using:

```
@GET
@Path( "{order_id}/document/{document_id}/file" )
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public MultipartBody getDocument( @PathParam( "order_id") int _orderId,  @PathParam( "document_id") int _documentId) throws Exception {

   FileInfo fileInfo = findFileInfo( _orderId, _documentId );

   List<Attachment> atts = new ArrayList<Attachment>();

   File internalFile = fileInfo.getActualFile();

   String fileName = fileInfo.getOriginalDocumentName();

   String fileSize = String.valueOf( internalFile.length() );

   ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"; size=" + fileSize );

   InputStream inputStreamToUse = new FileInputStream( internalFile );

   Attachment att = new Attachment(fileName, inputStreamToUse, cd);

   atts.add( att );

   return new MultipartBody(atts, true);    
}
```

I can't find any references in the [Migration Guides](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/migration-guides.html) to changes in this area and the style of the above method seems to match the one from the [getBooks2() method in the JAX-RS Multipart documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html#highlighter_731760).

Any guidance on what might be causing the different behaviour?

Comment: Possibly, but unsure.  Multiple clients of the web service, not all able to test and we'd like to guarantee compatibility before publishing new version of service which is only (in this case) and upgrade to the CXF and the minimal changes required to compile. Aside from that, no underlying code changed.  If CXF fixed an earlier problem where those attributes shouldn't have been included, that would be an acceptable explanation and will make any clients who were relying on it conform.

Comment: As your multipart has only one part (based on the code you provide), it makes sense that "start" (used to identify the first part, because multipart/mixed are ordered) has been dropped; same for "start-info". As for "type", I don't know, but wouldn't worry too much about it, since it is specified for the part below any way.

Comment: So, @smarquis, you're suggesting that CXF stopped generating the type attribute because it's redundant given what follows and the start-info and start attributes because they were erroneously (or redundantly) added for single-part bodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was done because apparently only a `multipart/related` media type may have optional `start` and `start-info` attributes according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2387.

A more complete discussion of the topic is on the CXF mailing list, particularly [this message](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201601.mbox/%3C5693909D.9010900%40gmail.com%3E) which indicates that `Content-Type` was broken as well.